# Div boxes vertically inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know, how to solve my following css problem, perhaps anybody can help:

[image: css Problem]
I don't know the height of the items, but the width should be 33%. If the max-height of the parent Div box ist reached, the next element should float to the right.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be possible to achieve what you're looking for with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ...

Comment: I'm using flexbox already in my project, but I couldn't find a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox columns.

https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/azqjg2kb/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 306px;
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid white;
  list-style: none;
}
```

I have created an unordered list which is set as a flex container with a column direction, and allowed wrapping.

https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/azqjg2kb/

Comment: Glad that it helped. you are welcome. have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you. I'm not sure about the structure you have. I just created with dummy structure

```css
    .flex-container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     align-content: flex-start;
     align-items: flex-start;
     width: 600px;
     max-height: 250px;
    }
    .flex-item {
     order: 0;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     align-self: flex-start;
     width: 33.33%;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid #777;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"> Element 1<br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 6</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 7</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Element 8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try CSS columns. They are a little bit tricky to use for anything complex but would do what you are asking for.

Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/hidanielle/pen/ZpRmPp) but the most important part is outlined below. On the container element, declare the amount of columns, since you want each item to be 33% width, I've put 3 columns. `column-gap` is the space between each column. After that it's important to put each child element to `width: 100%` as this is percent width of the column, and `display: inline-block`.

```
.container {
  max-height: 400px;
  columns: 3;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Browser support is [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=columns)

Answer (score 0):

.inline{width:100px;background:yellow;white-space:nowrap;display:inline;}

Content forContent forContent for